# Null Value, Exception

Tags: c#, sql, null

I am doing a project where i have to count a column's values in SQL Server, and return it's sum.

I use this query.

```
select sum(Charges) 
from Kitchen 
where Customer_ID = '1' 
  and Date Between 'Friday,January 19,2018' AND 'Sunday,January 21,2018';
```

It is working fine in SQL Server Management Studio. But when I am using this in C# code it is throwing an exception of null value.

Exception is.

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Here is the code for better understanding:

```
con.Open();

string selectSQLC = "select sum(Charges) from Kitchen where Customer_ID='"+txtCustomerID.Text  +"' and Date Between '"+dateofarrival +"' and '"+DateTime.Now+"'";

SqlCommand cmdCC = new SqlCommand(selectSQLC, con);

SqlDataReader rdCC;

rdCC = cmdCC.ExecuteReader();

while (rdCC.Read())
{
    KitchenBill = rdCC.GetInt32(0);
}

TotalAmount = KitchenBill + TotalAmount;   

con.Close();
```

[image: Here is the SS of SSMS]

Note: column datatype is `int`.

Please guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Don't build queries up like this, they are brittle and vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters.

Comment: Print out selectSQLC and paste it into SSMS

Comment: @DavidG Actually it is a school project and i have instructions to use queries.

Comment: Parameter still fit into queries...

Comment: your c# query is not exactly equivalent to the one you are using in Management Studio: you probably need to format the DateTime strings using ```string.Format("{0:D}", date)```

Comment: @Paparazzi Please see the Question. I have updated it

Comment: @DavidG Can you show me How?

Comment: @alainlompo Actually date is a varchar.

Comment: Not believing that is a print of  selectSQLC.

Comment: @Paparazzi Sorry I did not understand your statement.

Comment: @Uniquedesign when you print DateTime.Now you got something like: **21.01.2018 20:50:27** which is not the type of format your Sql server is expecting, hence you need to format the values correctly before sending the query from c# to your sql server

Comment: Show me where you print the value of selectSQLC.

Comment: @alainlompo ooh! ok.

Comment: @alainlompo Nope. Still same error.

Comment: Did you apply the formating to dateofarrival as well?

Comment: @alainlompo actually I have some textboxes which save the Date value of "arrival" and "departure" in the string Format. so I use their text property.Like this "txtarrival.text" and "txtdeparture.text"

Comment: There are many problems with creating SQL statements by concatenating strings so don't do that. Use a [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) to select dates and [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types) to pass them to the database.

Comment: You use SQL command in C#. Ok But this command will run on SQL server. So You should be careful to generate SQL command. Firstly, you look  DateTime.Now.ToString() . Is it suitable for your query?

Comment: You should get your teacher fired, unless the lesson is how not to write sql.

Comment: I bet you still have not printed the value of selectSQLC.  -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET is very easy to get wrong, and that SQL is hugely dangerous. I *strongly* recommend tools like Dapper to help here:

```
var KitchenBill = con.QuerySingle<int>(@"
    select sum(Charges) from Kitchen
    where Customer_ID=@customerID
    and Date Between @start and @end",
    new {
        customerId = txtCustomerID.Text,
        start = dateofarrival,
        end = DateTime.Now
    });

TotalAmount = KitchenBill + TotalAmount;
```

This solves parameterization, command building, and output processing all in one go. It'll even open and close the connection!

Additional note: be very careful with `DateTime.Now` and databases - it might be tricky around DST changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
 con.Open();

string selectSQLC = "select sum(Charges) from Kitchen where Customer_ID=@Customer_ID and Date Between @date1  and @date2";

SqlCommand cmdCC = new SqlCommand(selectSQLC, con);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@Customer_ID";
        param.Value         = txtCustomerID.Text;
SqlParameter paramd1  = new SqlParameter();
        paramd1.ParameterName = "@date1";
        paramd1.Value         = dateofarrival;
SqlParameter paramd2  = new SqlParameter();
        paramd2.ParameterName = "@date2";
        paramd2.Value         = DateTime.Now;
cmdCC.Parameters.Add(param);
cmdCC.Parameters.Add(paramd1);
cmdCC.Parameters.Add(paramd2);
 SqlDataReader rdCC;

rdCC = cmdCC.ExecuteReader();

while (rdCC.Read())
{
    KitchenBill = rdCC.GetInt32(0);
}

TotalAmount = KitchenBill + TotalAmount;   

con.Close();
```

Comment: Note the parameters can be simplified to `sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName="@date1", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value=dateofarrival });` and so on.

Comment: Yes, this is also true